# how do I find the name of a frame in chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome

I'm working with selenium and python and I do not know how to find the name of the frame in the HTML code on a website by clicking inspect. I would like to know where in the inspect (HTML) code that I can find the name of the frame

Comment: If this answer helped in your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Answer (score 0):

The `<frame>` tag used in HTML4 to define one particular window (frame) within a frameset. In HTML5 we use `<iframe>`.

In your case, you can simply right click in anywhere in the frame, and click on 'Inspect' and in the elements tab, you can find the `name / id` of the frame. You can select all `frame` related tags by pressing `CTRL` + `F` to search and type frame to select all frames in the `DOM`.

You can find XPath of that frame by right clicking that line, and clicking on 'Copy' > 'Copy XPath'.

For switching to a frame, we can also simply use the name of the frame, as follows. We can get the frame name, by right clicking on the element, and observing the HTML code in the developer tools panel's elements tab.

```
driver.switch_to_frame("frameName")
```